# How to display a very large text file located in local memory in android?

Tags: android, performance, webview

How can we display a very large text file size of 40mb to 70mb efficiently in android. I have tried to load the file in a web view but it took time to load.Please suggest the implementation.

Comment: `40mb` ? 40 milli bit?